# create more tables in stored procedures

Tags: mysql

I need to define one procedure who drops and creates 4 tables. I do this and tell me the procedure and tables was created, but if I call the procedure I don't see the tables (in Mysql).

```
delimiter $
create procedure tabele()
    begin
        drop table Medici;
        drop table Pacienti;
        drop table Cabinete;
        drop table Vizite;

    create table if not exists Medici(
        ID int(11) auto_increment primary key,
        Nume varchar(250),
        Prenume varchar(250),
        Statut enum('Primar','Specialist'),
        Specialitate varchar(250),
        Unique (Nume,Prenume));

    create table if not exists Pacienti (
        ID int(11) auto_increment primary key,
        Nume varchar(250),
        Prenume varchar(250),
        Unique(Nume,Prenume));

    create table if not exists Cabinete (
        ID int(11) auto_increment primary key,
        Nume varchar(250),
        Unique (Nume));

    create temporary table if not exists Vizite (
    ID int(11) auto_increment primary key,
    DataVizita date,
    OraIntrare time,
    NumePacient varchar(250),
    PrenumePacient varchar(250),
    NumeMedic Varchar(250),
    PrenumeMedic varchar(250),
    Cabinet text);

    end $
```

Comment: Works fine for me, how are attempting to see the tables in mysql?

Comment: I expect to see in database pfinal tables "Medici","Cabinete","Pacienti","Vizite" because i need to load data in tables.

Comment: And I do see them when I run the procedure - I asked how you are attempting to see the tables - ie using a select , describe or show create table or do you have some gui (phpmyadmin,mysqlworkbench, command line sql)

Comment: Are you sure you called the procedure in the database pfinal?

Comment: Yes. I find the problem,  i must correct the drop sintax in my procedure. Correct was drop table if exists ... ,after that the procedure create my tables. Thanks for help!